# if scrollview inherits from UIView how come my code below doesn't work?

Tags: ios

if scrollview inherits from UIView  how come my code below doesn't work?

DOBMonthTextField us an an IBOutlet for a UITextField.

```
[DOBMonthTextField setHidden:YES];
```

It stopped working when I made my UIVIEW underneath the text field a scrollview. The text field use to hide when I executed the code above. Now it doesn't hide.

Comment: Is the IBOutlet is connected, because sometimes when you cut-paste the views inside other views, the connections go missing. Secondly, considering DOBMonthTextField is an IBOutlet, you should use camelCasing style for naming variables and classes.

Comment: Good lord that's probably it. I did cut and paste, but I'll try out tonight.

Comment: @Zen that was the issue.It's the little things. Thanks! Answer the question so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While changing the views in nib files via cut-paste, the `IBoutlet` connections of those views go missing (disconnected), so you always have to reconnect them after pasting.

Check your connections whenever some code for a view created in nib/storyboards used to work earlier but does not after some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Because `hidden` (or its setter, `setHidden:`) is a property of an instance of DOBMonthTextField, not the class itself. Classes don't have properties in Objective C. Here's an example of roughly what you should be doing instead:

```
DOBMonthTextField *someInstance = [[DOBMonthTextField alloc] init];
[someInstance setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: I bet that he has just NAMED his instance poorly. Else he'd get a solid warning/error that no class method setHidden is found ... so I dont think this applies but should teach OP to use proper naming :D

Comment: DOBMonthTextField is a UITextField

Comment: Its an an IBOutlet for a UITextField.